# How to serve index.html if it exists instead of React app

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm setting up an Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) server to host a ReactJS single-page app (so it returns the app for any non-existing URL), but there are also some static HTML pages I'm serving (all under one particular directory named `projects`). Right now, if you hit any directory without a file specified, it serves my React app (from `/var/www/html/index.html`) in , but if the directory exists and contains a file named `index.html`, I need it to serve the index.html, like Apache does by default. The projects directory is in /var/www/html along with everything else. What's wrong with my config?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory  "/var/www/html"> 
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [last]

        RewriteRule ^ - [last]

        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added one more `RewriteCond` with `!-d` to test if a directory by the name is present.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory  "/var/www/html"> 
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [last]

        RewriteRule ^ - [last]

        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Seems to work!